# Why we are creating two different mailer view(welcome_email.text.erb and welcome_email.html.erb) for single mailer action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Many times I have created two different formats for action mailer view templates like welcome_email.text.erb and welcome_email.html.erb. But I didn't find the proper solution for why we are creating those files?

can you please any one help me?

Comment: Because the html version of an email might differ from its pure text version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the .html.erb is for html enabled email clients, the .text.erb is for those whom receive emails in plain text mode.

the "actual why" is so your audience receives your message properly